# Difference between FileProvider.getUriForFile and Uri.Parse() in Kotlin Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, uri, android-fileprovider

can anyone please help me with the difference between  FileProvider.getUriForFile and Uri.Parse() in Kotlin Android Studio? I am working on a code in Kotlin to create a excel file and share it on various apps like Gmail, Whatsapp, etc. My issue is:

1. when I have to share the file on Gmail, if I use `Uri.Parse(filepath)` to get the URI of the file, I get an "*Unable to attach file*" so I have to use FileProvider then it works fine.
2. when I have to share the file on Whatsapp, its vice versa, i.e. if I use `FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,context.applicationContext.packageName.toString() + ".provider",file)` to get the URI of the file, I get an "*Sharing failed. Please try again*" so I have to use Uri.Parse(filepath) then it works fine.

My code for share:

```
private fun ShareViaEmail(context: Context, path: String, file: File) {

    if (!file.exists()){
        context.ShowToast( "File doesn't exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        return;
    }

    val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
        context,
        context.applicationContext.packageName.toString() + ".provider",
        file
    )
    Log.i(TAG, uri.toString())

    val intentShare = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
    intentShare.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    intentShare.type = "*/*"
    //intentShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(path))
    intentShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri)
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intentShare, "Share the file ..."))
}

private fun Share(context: Context, path: String, file: File) {

    if (!file.exists()){
        context.ShowToast( "File doesn't exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        return;
    }

    Log.i(TAG, Uri.parse(path).toString())

    val intentShare = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
    intentShare.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    intentShare.type = "*/*"
    intentShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(path))
    //For system files: intentShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+path))
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intentShare, "Share the file ..."))
}
```

Thanks in Advance!